# Pairing two Textboxes such that the numerical value of one must be lesser-than or equal to the other

Tags: c#, winforms

To expand upon the title, I must create pairs of textboxes which together specify a numerical range (such as, say, 5 to 10, or -17 to -17). These textboxes must be such that the textbox which specifies the lower bound must have a lesser numerical value than the textbox which specifies the upper bound. One obvious solution come to mind: Ad hoc code in the parent form that handles the update event by checking their values. While this gets the job done, it strikes me as extremely inelegant and icky.

I suspect there must be a solid, OO-solution to this issue, but I'm not certain what that would be. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Why not put both controls in a UserControl - this control then encapsulates the functionality you want. They can even both subscribe to the same change event within the UserControl and you can just check the sender to determine which box is which.

Comment: I didn't even think of that. That's much cleaner than putting it directly into the parent form.

You should submit that as an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm. As a downside, that DOES leave the placement of the two textboxes as rigid (unless I create a new UserControl for every arrangement). While that works for my specific use of it, I'd still be interested in a mechanism within the Textbox itself (extended, if need be) that provided this functionality.

Comment: You could make this a feature of the user control - when you create the control, it could have a setting that arranges the controls as you like. For example, you could create a table layout panel with two columns or two rows to contain the text boxes depending on whether you wanted something "Horizontal" or "Vertical". The only other way I could think of doing this, off the top of my head, is to have an extension method or helper class that lets you register a pair of controls that it wires up to a change event. When one of them changes, the helper class searches for the other control, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a thought - create a class called "TextBoxManager":

```
public class TextBoxManager
{

    public List<Tuple<TextBox, TextBox>> LowerHigherPairs { get; set; }


    public TextBoxManager()
    {
        LowerHigherPairs = new List<Tuple<TextBox, TextBox>>();
    }


    public void RegisterTextBoxes(TextBox lower, TextBox higher)
    {
        lower.Leave += TextBoxFocusLost;
        higher.Leave += TextBoxFocusLost;
        LowerHigherPairs.Add(new Tuple<TextBox, TextBox>(lower, higher));

    }



    public void TextBoxFocusLost(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox senderBox = sender as TextBox;

        Tuple<TextBox, TextBox> matchingPair = LowerHigherPairs.Find(x => x.Item1 == senderBox || x.Item2 == senderBox);

        if (matchingPair != null)
        {

            if (matchingPair.Item1 == senderBox)
            {
                //We know we should compare with the value in Item2.Text
            }
            else
            {
                //We know we should compare with the value in Item1.Text
            }

        }

    }


}
```

In your form, declare this as a class level variable:

```
TextBoxManager higherLowerManager = new TextBoxManager();
```

Then, in your form OnLoad event, just register the pair of textboxes you want to manage:

```
higherLowerManager.RegisterTextBoxes(lowerEntryTextBox, higherEntryTextBox);
```

As you can see this class will then pair the two and subscribe them to a common event where we can work out which was which and perform the appropriate logic.

The other way to do this is to use a UserControl - this loses flexibility in terms of dynamic layout, but neatly encapsulates the entire interaction. Also, from a UI perspective, if the controls influence each other, then they should be close together anyway.

Comment: Very nice. Exactly what I'm looking for. +1 and Accepted.